# How to hide image upload option from url in Jodit Editor React

Tags: reactjs, image, upload, jodit

I want to hide image upload option from URL in Jodit Editor, Currently it showing two options to upload:
[image: Jodit Editor Image Upload Snapshot]

I wanted to keep only upload from local system option and remove/hide the next image url tab.

I tried over change the config of Jodit editor by adding tabs properties, but it doesn't work.

uploader: {
insertImageAsBase64URI: true,
tabs: 'file'
},